Angular NGINX fail on parameter request
i front on strange error, i have this route
{path: 'applogin/:appname', component: BusinessManagementComponent}

i want call BusinessManagementComponent with parameter appname, on component logic i use
this.ApplicationName = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('appname'); for get param value. This snippet on dev mode work fine, i mean if i use ng serve for launch build. If i use production env, with NGINX deploy i have 500 error with this log:
12 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.html", client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /applogin/ HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"

this is my nginx conf
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;


    root root /var/www/html/browser;
    index index.html;


    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }


    location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|map|json|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|txt|xml)$ {
        expires 6M;
        access_log off;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }


    gzip on;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
}

i want call page with this url
http://localhost/applogin/testapp

someone have some idea, how fix it?

try this Improved handling of Angular routes
location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?$query_string;
}

the url is http://localhost/applogin/testapp
not http://localhost/applogin?appname=testapp

@Chintan Your suggestion does not provide any improvement since the URL that the Angular router sees in the browser's address bar will not get changed by using it. Moreover, it will break the nginx configuration if the alias directive is used instead of root in the location where the try_files directive resides, due to this nginx bug. Consider it as an example of consequences that can occur if you blindly follow the AI-generated suggestions.
